# Are async hooks execution IDs reassignable?

Tags: node.js, async-hooks

I've been wanting to maintain some data, on the basis of execution Ids and triggering async Ids provided by async_hooks. somehow I've observed that for some triggering context, let's say context "a" with execution-id 20, the context get created, another context "b"(execution-id 30) gets triggered from within "a" and this context get destroyed, even before complete execution "b"(ok callbacks). So, what is the possibility of the execution-id 20 being reassigned?